# How to use a proxy in python requests, when the password for the proxy contains a question mark?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, proxy-server

I need to get some data using an API.

I need something like:

```
response = requests.get(url)
```

which works only locally.

Otherwise, I'm getting following error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')
```

I found out that this can be resolved by using proxies.

So I tried first with my private credentials:

```
response = requests.get(url, proxies={"https": "http://MY_USERNAME:MY_PASSWORD@proxyserver:port"})
```

That works both locally and in prod.

However, instead of private credentials, I need to use some service credentials. The problem is password contains a question mark "?".

When I run

```
response = requests.get(url, proxies={"https": "http://SERVICE_USERNAME:SERVICE_PASSWORD@proxyserver:port"})
```

I get an error:

```
requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Failed to parse: http://SERVICE_USERNAME:SERVICE_PASSWORD@proxyserver:port
```

I also tried the approach suggested in the [requests doc](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies) where I exported `"http://SERVICE_USERNAME:SERVICE_PASSWORD@proxyserver:port"` to a variable `HTTPS_PROXY`.

However, I got same error as without proxies.

Comment: What if you URL-encode the password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never tried proxy with password but try this code below and give me the result

```
import requests
from urllib import parse

url = 'http://example.com'

password = 'pass???word!!!'
username = 'username'

proxyserver = 'proxyserver'
port = '8080'


password = parse.quote(password) 
username = parse.quote(username)
response = requests.get(url, proxies={"https": f"http://{username}:{password}@{proxyserver}:{port}"})
```

Comment: Thank you, it works.

Though it's a bit surprising to me that it actually changes a password. But it seems like that's how it is supposed to work.